# Monero testnet forked on block 1982800; how is it possible and what are the implications for mainnet?

Tags: hard-fork, testnet

I have a testnet node running on `0.17.3.2-release`. At the moment the node reports the following tip:

```
print_height
1999140

print_block 1999139
timestamp: 1654876411 (2022-06-10 15:53:31)
previous hash: 427d4f740d30dde137b84d5f87628908910634ca417ca02a18cd8c61026efecf
nonce: 2111132182
is orphan: 0
height: 1999139
depth: 0
hash: 27b13519740456f14df623b19d867891622bd9a0e30941e1b24cb5f9db7d59bb
difficulty: 59693
cumulative difficulty: 870397914516
POW hash: ae6dad3599d35096149a64f78cb2a552522205dac00f84e26d37612e70ed0000
block size: 84
block weight: 84
long term weight: 84
num txes: 0
reward: 1.409632355639
miner tx hash: 27fd02b90e334d914be5002384ffc82ca7792d9435fc481faeadb20709dbeaa3
{
  "major_version": 14, 
  "minor_version": 14, 
  "timestamp": 1654876411, 
  "prev_id": "427d4f740d30dde137b84d5f87628908910634ca417ca02a18cd8c61026efecf", 
  "nonce": 2111132182, 
  "miner_tx": {
    "version": 2, 
    "unlock_time": 1999199, 
    "vin": [ {
        "gen": {
          "height": 1999139
        }
      }
    ], 
    "vout": [ {
        "amount": 1409632355639, 
        "target": {
          "key": "3ee8b87e330bce82bc9ab7d0d2a3179d9dfde8acf3e5d4177bc815a8ae867374"
        }
      }
    ], 
    "extra": [ 1, 142, 119, 158, 122, 227, 69, 190, 132, 237, 36, 176, 253, 239, 125, 199, 151, 37, 7, 184, 88, 193, 53, 57, 205, 51, 148, 178, 213, 206, 255, 179, 82
    ], 
    "rct_signatures": {
      "type": 0
    }
  }, 
  "tx_hashes": [ ]
}
```

However, the https://testnet.xmrchain.net/ explorer reports last block `1999965` with hash of `302af3b09f1c2cbe59b5fc6e701bc66cf7e01c40aebadbd505880dbd711e3b37` and version `0.17.0.0-8349cfe4a` which is older than mine.

I quickly bisected to find the block where chains had split and the first different block was `1982800`, where view tags have been introduced.

How is it possible that my node accepted the chain still running with `v14` transactions (as I understand, the HF introduced `v15`)? Can such an uncontrollable split also happen on the mainnet?

What peer should I connect to in order to download the newer chain?

Comment: I have the same problem, blockchain forked at the same height. Do you know how to fix it? Have you downloaded newest node version? I'm wondering if the problem is with not finding right peers or just software selecting wrong blockchain.

Comment: @JakubM if you forked you are not running a release and are likely running master. See [answer below](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/13661/7493). To fix, run the current release (not master), and pop blocks to where you forked.

Comment: @jtgrassie Oh, just noticed OP specified node version. I'm running version 0.17.2.3, will update to 0.17.3.2 soon and I'll try to download blocks again.

Comment: @jtgrassie shouldn't the node automatically pop blocks when encountering a longer chain?

Comment: @emesik I don't think so but try it. Install and run the release, then observe. I think you'll need to pop blocks though manually, not because of chain length, but because you have a mixture of incorrect chain protocol versions downloaded and validated.

Comment: @jtgrassie I built latest master. Actually, when I specify a node with different chain to connect to, the node does nothing, only the DEBUG log is full of exceptions of bad_weak_ptr. If I run it without additional arguments, it syncs from the chain it did run on when using release build.

Comment: @emesik "latest master" is not a release. You need to use a release and pop blocks to where you forked.

Answer (score 1):

> How is it possible that my node accepted the chain still running with v14 transactions (as I understand, the HF introduced v15)?

The latest testnet hardfork in [release v17.3.2 is 14](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/v0.17.3.2/src/hardforks/hardforks.cpp#L97).

> Can such an uncontrollable split also happen on the mainnet?

Hardfork v15 is not in a tagged release yet, so there isn't any "split".